# Nvida X Server dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I need to set up dual screen. I've tried countless of ways but failed. Right now, I have re-installed x server so everything is at it's default.
How do I switch to dual monitor with one being portrait (and left of) the other, the main screen?

Comment: What card do you have? Have you installed any drivers? Are you using the open source drivers? Your question needs a lot more information before we can help you out. Please edit your question with your hardware/drivers information and the steps you already took before. The more information the better the chances that someone will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Nvidia-Xserver-settings for that if you have an Nvidia card (guess so from post title).

1. Go to X server display configuration.
2. Click on detect displays and click on your extra monitor.
3. In configuration select Twinview.
4. Choose resolution and position, left of, right of, etc...
5. Apply changes...and voila, it should work.

If you want to automate the process you can also consider using [Disper](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/) it was my life saver for everyday use of dual monitors.

Comment: I did that but that wouldn't allow me to switch my sub-monitor to portrait. It's that switching that I am having problem with. Would you like to see my xorg.conf file and advise from there? :)

Disper seemed difficult to install. Thanks!

Comment: can you specify what do you mean by portrait? thanks!